# How to search a String in Class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, nlp

I am developing an app in which i have some data fetched from net into a class.
Class is

```
public class Detail
{
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Education> education { get; set; }
        public City city { get; set; }
        public List<Work> work { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
        public string DegreeName { get; set; }
}

public class City 
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
public class Work
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Data is stored for a person in the above class.

Now i want to search for a string say `q=" Which Manager Graduated From USA ?"`

So i want it to search for the above query...

Based on how much words matched, i want to give the Name of user. So searching for person if he is *a Manager Graduated From USA ?* (may be less words, for search like some *Director from India*)

The approach i am trying to look for words like *Manager* in `Work` and *Graduate* in `Education` and *Location* for `USA`

I am making an array of search string

```
string[] qList = q.Split(' ');
```

and then traverse through the class. But i don't have any idea of how to (efficiently) look for data in the class.

And is my approach good enough for search or is there any better option ?

Comment: Can you tell us what properties are in the Education, City and Work objects?

Comment: well the point is which interface do you provide to the asker and how do you know which term should be searched in which property ?

Comment: How specific can you expect your `q` strings to be?  Will the strings always be in that syntax?  That is, will you always be searching for a person whose `Work` contains the second word as above?  Also I believe you meant something more like, "Graduated in `Education` and USA in `City`.  I don't see a `Location` field in your `Detail` class.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk : No, no particular syntax...that's why i am trying to use Array of query string

Comment: Natural language query is something you should try and avoid. Creating an obvious and responsive interface to "lead" people into how you _can_ query your data seems to be much more preferable.

Comment: Watch out for inner platform anti-pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect

Answer (score 2):

What you're developing is a human readable and writable query language. Starting with a string split may be a, well, start but imagine the search possibilities:
Search for people in a city or a range of cities, search for people that worked for a top 500 company or in a certain field.

For this purpose you should develop a query language. With an easy to change and documented grammar. Take a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) a Parser Generator that plays nice with C#/.NET.

Comment: I think better advice would be for him **not** to develop a query language.

Comment: Developing a linguistic appealing query language is definitely a live long task :)

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk how does these Shopping site do their search...isn't that some similar ?

Comment: Amazon and Google use extremely sophisticated graph traversal algorithms.  Very *very* generally, they have internal data bases which consist of linked nodes of character groups with edges between nodes loosely correlated to the semantic connection of English words.  A search over this graph consists of a node traversal in which moving from node to node has some cost. The search returns results based on the cost of the the traversals.  The graphs used are dynamic, and change in response to user searches, popularity of past search results, and manual updates.

Comment: Hundreds of computer scientists have been working on natural language processing for decades.  Do not reinvent the wheel.  Look at your problem and determine what level of sophistication it requires.  If the syntax you want to parse is regular, use the Regex library in .NET.  If the syntax is more complicated, then Saintedlama's suggested tool, ANTLR, would be a great tool to try out.

Answer (score 2):

I have somehow concern about the mechanism you are trying to implement, if user types `q=" Manager Graduated From USA ?"`, mean doesn't put the word 'which' in it, so you will have to go for query language like ANTLR as suggested.

My recommendation is to give dropdowns to user, first must contain values of Work Property, 2nd must contain values of education and than a text box to enter the City.

After you pass these values to your method, use LINQ to get the data from your collection like:

```
var filteredResults = from result in YOURDETAILCOLLECTION
                      where result.city.Contains(YOURCITYTEXTBOXVALUE)
                      select result;
```

You can search for the mechanism, how to `where` in `LINQ` on a `List`.

Comment: This seems to be the most sensible approach so far.

Comment: If you have to use a single text box, than in tooltip of textbox or use JQuery to water mark the text, and tell the user that first enter Work than a space than education and than a space and provide city.

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, try indexing your data using [Lucene .NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) or a similar search technology, like Solr or ElasticSearch. These technologies are optimized for search and provide you with lots of options to improve the ranking of your results. It can easily answer the question in your opening post and it's very fast. It would be very hard to implement this functionality on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of fields which you KNOW will exist - like Education and Work - I would recommend having an array of synonyms and words-related-to for each field.

So, for Education, you could have a list of words like this:

```
Graduate, University, School, Learning, Taught e.t.c
```

Do something like this?

Obviously, you won't be able to match EVERY single word, but it might be worth a shot?

Or you could try including tags in each field, rather than just words. So rather than them putting "I graduated from University", you have an Education field, and then a University sub-field, where they put the name.

It's all about limiting errors, bearing in mind humans can make millions of errors that you just CAN'T deal with programmatically.